# meteor installing packages twice - client and server

Tags: meteor

I noticed that upon adding packages to Meteor with the command "meteor add packageName" (e.g. accounts-Facebook), all of them are added in the client/packages folder, which subsequently will put them all in the browser.

Why does this happen and how can this be prevented? They seem to be installed twice, once in server/packages and once in client/packages, I don't understand.

Meteor should put only client-relevant packages in the client folder.

Thanks!

Comment: The packages folder should be in the root of the project, not in the client or the server folders. Not sure how you got into that situation. Packages use a different structure to determine what files go to the client and what files go to the server, or both.

Comment: I have added folders server, client, packages manually to the root folder of my app but nothing gets written there, after reinstalling the packages. should i configure something, so that the packages are written in the packages folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this folder structure, in linux file explorer all I see is the folders i made manually in the root of the project, but in sublime text i see this folder structure as well in the root: .meteor > local > build > programs > client, ctl, server. That is where the packages are being written, in all those 3 folders (client, ctl, server)

Comment: Oh well that makes sense now.. any folder or file in linux that starts with a period(.) is "hidden", the ```.meteor``` folder is not really something you need to worry about and can be thought of as part of the "magic" that is Meteor! Just ignore it, trust me!

Comment: i see; but then, why do I see all the packages in the browser itself? when I inspect in chrome F12 "sources" tab, i see all packages, does this mean they are all visible in the client, should I worry about this? please write as answer so I can give credits.